# how to create an icon on image with inkwell after Click on the image in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

I made a grid view in the flutter app. But like the Pictures on the below link , I want to create an icon on the picture and change the background color After tap the picture,

I've been looking for ways, but I've finally got a question. I'd appreciate it from the bottom of my heart if you'd let me know.

***Please enter img link(below)***

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instaclone-2-fd9de.appspot.com/o/post%2F12344.png?alt=media&token=89d46c03-83ba-4d30-b716-e9b718c1340b

```
 Widget _bodyBuilder() {
//  TODO : 그 예시를 어떻해 stream View로 보여줄것인가
return StreamBuilder <QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _commentStream(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    if(!snapshot.hasData){
      return Center(child:  CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    var items =  snapshot.data?.documents ??[];
    var fF = items.where((doc)=> doc['style'] == "오피스룩").toList();
    var sF = items.where((doc)=> doc['style'] == "로맨틱").toList();
    var tF = items.where((doc)=> doc['style'] == "캐주").toList();
    fF.addAll(sF);
    fF.addAll(tF);
    fF.shuffle();

    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            childAspectRatio: 0.6,
            mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 2.0),
        itemCount: fF.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _buildListItem(context, fF[index]);
        });
  },
);
```

}

```
      Widget _buildListItem(context, document) {
    return Ink.image(
     image : NetworkImage(document['thumbnail_img']),
     fit : BoxFit.cover,
      child: new InkWell(
       //I think we need to get something in here....
        onTap: (){},
      ),
     );
  }
```

Comment: It is select option, it can be possible if you send the full code.

Comment: I just added it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create List of Image which have `isSelected` value and when the user clicks on item them set true/false base of the old value which have `imageURL` and `isSelected` variable. First, you should store value in List Of Image obj. which coming from Firebase/API then flow below step. I have created a demo and post here. Please take reference.

**Example code**

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  List<ImageData> imageList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imageList = ImageData.getImage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: 0.5,
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 2.0),
        itemCount: imageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (builder, index) {
          return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  imageList[index].isSelected = !imageList[index].isSelected;
                });
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  _getImage(imageList[index].imageURL),
                  Opacity(
                    opacity: imageList[index].isSelected ? 1 : 0,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: double.infinity,
                          color: Colors.black38,
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.check,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _getImage(url) => Image.network(
        url,
        height: 500,
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class ImageData {
  String imageURL;
  bool isSelected;
  int id;

  ImageData(this.imageURL, this.isSelected, this.id);

  static List<ImageData> getImage() {
    return [
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/200', false, 1),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/100', false, 2),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/300', false, 3),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/400', false, 4),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/500', false, 5),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/600', false, 6),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/700', false, 7),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/800', false, 8),
      ImageData('https://picsum.photos/900', false, 9),
    ];
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know !!! I'll try and let you know.

Comment: If you really helpful of my solution then accept it :)

Comment: As per your code, you should add images into *imageList* after  *fF.shuffle();* and user reference in GridView

Comment: I just did. Thank you so much.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem with the code you posted, so I posted the question again with full code. Can you take a look?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017653/how-to-chage-an-icon-on-grid-view-img-after-click-in-flutter

Comment: Can you share response of firebase so I can use it.

Comment: I will check it